# How to really install GNOME desktop

Tags: unity, 14.04, gnome

I want to replace unity desktop by Gnome desktop. I have installed Gnome-shell but what's I get is not what I want. I want to have the same result as if I installed [Ubuntu Gnome](http://ubuntugnome.org/). I have tried fresh install of Ubuntu Gnome but now I have a problem : I can't start any of my installed Ubuntu without efi mode and the Ubuntu Gnome I installed stuck at Gnome logo when I run with efi mode. So I restored my system to its original state.

When I installed Gnome-shell many things stayed the same as in Unity. The font are those of Unity, scrollbar, window bar color the logo at start ...etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

This is the Ubuntu Gnome desktop metapackage; as for the font, theme, icons and other personal settings you would have to manually set them yourself.